# How to deploy pagelayouts in salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have one basic query. I have record type contains 2 pagelayouts,added screen shot below.

[image]

In Lightning Page screen shot:

[image]

In Lightning it shows userdatarecordpage for both userdate layout and workItemuser dataLayout.

***My questions:***

If I want to add related list,first I need to add it in classic,then only it appearing in Lightning.Simply If I drag related lists in lightning nothing will appear.

**So In that case which layout I need to deploy to another enviornment? (classic layouts or Lightning layouts) ???**

If I move classic layouts in another sandbox automatically Lightning 'user data page' will move?

if I Want to make any changes I need to do in classic,automatically will it reflect in Lightning pages?

Both classic and Lightning pages are same?

My doubts is i can write below script,I can easily retrieve lightning page also

```
<types>
    <members>User_Data_Record_Page</members>
    <name>FlexiPage</name>
</types>
<version>41.0</version>
```

I got doubts in both classic and Lightning page layouts. Can anyone explain me the difference with screen shot.Morever this question is more related to deployement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record Detail, Related Lists, and Related List - Single, and Related List - Quick Links components within Lightning Record Pages are "driven" by the Page Layout assigned to the user and record type.

Information about selected related lists shown by these components is stored in the Page Layout, not the Lightning Record Page. The Lightning Record Page is not an analogue of a page layout; it is a new kind of metadata.

The Record Page and associated Page Layouts can be deployed together, but don't have to be. If the Page Layouts are already present in the target org and haven't been modified in the source org, there's no need to deploy them. Page Layouts are deployed with the [`Layout`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm) type in `package.xml`.

Comment: You are saying if we deploy pagelayout. no nessary to deploy the record page??

Comment: No. I'm saying they are independent entities. They can be deployed together or separately, although it is possible you'd encounter errors if you deploy a Lightning Record Page with a lot of Related List configuration to an org whose page layouts don't have those Related Lists.

Comment: Thanks david....